# Safari Extension And Download Links

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I'm working on a safari extension. I've included a start script in it, but it is not working with download link. for instance if I navigate to www.example.com/example.zip script is not getting called. I was wondering if it is possible to get it to work with download links?

Comment: An URL that leads to a file download will never be loaded into the web browser context.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Then what is the best approach for taking control of a download?

Comment: Download dialog can't be controlled once it has been presented to the user. The farthest thing you could do is to put an event listeners on every links to either do something before the download dialog appears or prevent it from being clicked. You'll have to parse the link URL manually to determine if it points to a file download or a normal web page.

Comment: Not all the download links are straight like www.example.com/test.dmg some of them might be like www.example.com/download?id=144 so only parsing the urls is not enough and if I try to evaluate every link by sending a request that will be a huge overhead.

Comment: What does your script should do when the link eventually points to a file download? Perhaps there's an alternative solution?

Comment: It should send the link to another application and prevent the download dialogue.

Comment: That's not possible since the web browser application has full control. Allowing script to have that kind of access would be a security violation. The only thing you can do is to put a notice on the page explaining that the file requires a specific application and the file must be downloaded in order to open it with the application. If the file is a PDF, a Flash animation, a video, or an audio, then a web browser plugin can be used instead of external application to open the file within the web browser.

Comment: I want the external application to handle the download. There are download manager programs out there able to catch safari downloads. So there must be a way.

Comment: @AbcdEfg : Did you find a way to redirect Safari downloads ?